# MVC website building xml sitemap for google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I'm trying to build xml sitemap of my website to submit to google, but unfortunately any crawlers like A1 sitemap builder, and other online tools cannot go further than first page and giving me Internal Server Error 500. I know because it's a MVC site it's required additional settings that should be done in IIS. Could someone help me to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the following [sitemap project on CodePlex](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant A1 Sitemap Generator? :)

Anyhow, error 500 means "internal server error"

If your browser does not give this error, it's probably a config issue:

- user agent not recognized by server (try other useragent in A1SG)
- unexpected HTTP requests headers (try other HTTP engine in A1SG)

Don't rule out e.g. HTTP request headers. I once encountered a website that would barf if the Accept-Language request header did not match the local language :)